# How to load angular2 files to Django template?

Tags: python, django, angular, frontend

I have app structure like this:

```
├── project
|   |── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── views.py
├── static
|   ├── app
|   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
|   │   ├── app.component.ts
|   │   ├── app.route.ts
│   │   ├── component1.component.ts
|   │   ├── component2.component.ts 
│   │   └── main.ts
|   ├── system.config.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── typings.json
├── db.sqlite3
├── LICENSE
├── manage.py
```

and I'm trying to load angular2 files into my django template `index.html`, so the file looks like this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<base href=/ > 
<title>Hello! </title> 
<meta charset=UTF-8> 
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> 


   <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('{%static '/app/main' %}').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

      <link href="{%static '/css/stylesheet.css' %}">
      <link href="{%static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
 </head> 
 <body> 


    <img src="{%static '/assets/logo.png' %}"></img>
      <as-my-app>Loading...</as-my-app>

  </body> 
  </html>
```

My problem is that all the static files load just fine, but my browser constantly shows error while loading `/static/app/main` saying it wasn't found. How come Django can't find it if it finds other static files?

Comment: Did you try to run `tsc` command (or `tsc main.ts`) to compile your ts files?

Comment: yes. I have in the same directory all `.js` , `.js.map` and `.ts` files

Comment: Take a look at the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested single quotes and your file name is `main.js` not `main`, you need also to remove the first `/`. Let me know if the following line of code solves your issue:

```
System.import("{% static 'app/main.js' %}")
```

Comment: now it gives me `Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app/main.js`

Comment: Did you install the package? `npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic`

Comment: I ended up adding `.js` files bundled with webpack.